# Paging 3 Library with Jetpack Compose Not calling the load method after initial load

Tags: android, pagination, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3, android-native-library

I am trying to use jetpack compose paging 3 library with start and limit, it loads the first items, but when I scroll trough the list it doesn't call the load method again.

I placed multiple logs, and I can see that the method is called just once, initially and then nothing happens after that. I really don't know what is wrong here. This is my code:

const val PAGE_SIZE = 30

```
class PhotosPagingSource (private val photosApi: PhotosApi) : PagingSource<Int, Photos>() {
    
    override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<Int>): LoadResult<Int, Photos> {

        return try {
            val page = params.key ?: 0
            val start = page * PAGE_SIZE
            val limit = params.loadSize
            
            val response = photosApi.getPhotos(start, limit)
            val photos = PhotosMapper.mapPhotosDTO(response)

            LoadResult.Page(
                data = photos,
                prevKey = if (page == 0) null else page - 1,
                nextKey = if (response.isEmpty()) null else page + 1
            )
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            LoadResult.Error(e)
        }
    }

    override fun getRefreshKey(state: PagingState<Int, Photos>): Int? {
        return state.anchorPosition
    }

}

class PhotosRepositoryImpl  @Inject constructor(
    private val photosApi: PhotosApi,
): PhotosRepository {


    override suspend fun getPhotos(): Flow<PagingData<Photos>> {

        return  Pager(config = PagingConfig(pageSize = 30, prefetchDistance = 3 )) {
            PhotosPagingSource(photosApi)
        }.flow
    }
}

@HiltViewModel
class HomeViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: PhotosRepository
) : ViewModel() {

    init {
        getPhotos()
    }

    private var _pagingFlow: MutableStateFlow<PagingData<Photos>> =
        MutableStateFlow(value = PagingData.empty())
    val pagingFlow: StateFlow<PagingData<Photos>> = _pagingFlow

    private fun getPhotos() {

        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            repository.getPhotos()
                .distinctUntilChanged()
                .cachedIn(viewModelScope)
                .collect {
                _pagingFlow.value = it
            }
        }
    }

}

val lazyPagingItems = homeViewModel.pagingFlow.collectAsLazyPagingItems()
            val state = lazyPagingItems.loadState
            val listState = rememberLazyListState()

            val pagingData = lazyPagingItems.itemSnapshotList

            when {

                state.refresh is LoadState.Loading && pagingData.size == 0 -> {
                    ShimmerHome()
                }

                state.refresh is LoadState.Loading && pagingData.size == 0 -> {
                    LoadingComposable()

                }

                state.refresh is LoadState.Error -> {
                    TODO()
                }

                state.append is LoadState.Loading -> {
                    LoadingComposable()

                }

                state.append is LoadState.Error -> {
                    TODO()
                }

                else -> {
                    LazyColumn(
                        modifier = Modifier,
                        state = listState,
                        contentPadding = PaddingValues(8.dp),
                        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
                        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                        content = {
                            items(items = pagingData) { pagingData ->
                                if (pagingData != null) {
                                    PhotosCard(
                                        photo = pagingData,
                                        onCardClicked = {TODO() }
                                    )
                                }
                            }
                        })
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In jetpack don't use `itemSnapshotList` and work only with `lazyPagingItems`. The thing is you have to use `LazyPagingItems#get(index: Int)` to get item and also notify paging data about that you are getting close to end of the page, from docs:

> Returns the presented item at the specified position, notifying Paging of the item access to trigger any loads necessary to fulfill prefetchDistance.

With `itemSnapshotList` pager doesn't know that you scrolled to bottom and need load another page.

Updated code:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun PagingTest(homeViewModel: HomeViewModel = hiltViewModel()) {
    val lazyPagingItems = homeViewModel.pagingFlow.collectAsLazyPagingItems()
    val state = lazyPagingItems.loadState
    val listState = rememberLazyListState()

    when {

        state.refresh is LoadState.Loading && lazyPagingItems.itemCount == 0 -> {
            ShimmerHome()
        }

        state.refresh is LoadState.Loading && lazyPagingItems.itemCount == 0 -> {
            LoadingComposable()
        }

        state.refresh is LoadState.Error -> {
            TODO()
        }

        state.append is LoadState.Loading -> {
            LoadingComposable()
        }

        state.append is LoadState.Error -> {
            TODO()
        }

        else -> {
            LazyColumn(
                modifier = Modifier,
                state = listState,
                contentPadding = PaddingValues(8.dp),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                content = {
                    items(count = lazyPagingItems.itemCount) { index ->
                        lazyPagingItems.get(index = index)?.let { photo ->
                            PhotosCard(
                                photo = pagingData,
                                onCardClicked = { TODO() }
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Krisxxx When my answer solved your problem can you mark it as correct please?